# Jenkins pipeline with parallel

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Here is my Jenkins pipeline that i am trying to execute. I am following [this tutorial](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#using-multiple-nodes):

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('one') {
            parallel "first" : {               
                    echo "hello"                
            },
            "second": {                
                    echo "world"            
            }
        }
        stage('two') {
            parallel "first" : {               
                    echo "hello"                
            },
            "second": {                
                    echo "world"            
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But the job fails with following message.

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 4: Unknown stage section "parallel". Starting with version 0.5, steps in a stage must be in a steps block. @ line 4, column 9.
           stage('one') {
           ^

WorkflowScript: 12: Unknown stage section "parallel". Starting with version 0.5, steps in a stage must be in a steps block. @ line 12, column 9.
           stage('two') {
           ^

WorkflowScript: 4: Nothing to execute within stage "one" @ line 4, column 9.
           stage('one') {
           ^

WorkflowScript: 12: Nothing to execute within stage "two" @ line 12, column 9.
           stage('two') {
           ^

4 errors
```

Can someone please help me out why this is failing.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You need to add a steps block after your stage declaration.

```java
    pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Example Stage 1') {
            steps {
                parallel(
                        "step 1": { echo "hello" },
                        "step 2": { echo "world" },
                        "step 3": { echo "world" }
                )
            }
        }
        stage('Example Stage 2') {
            steps {
                parallel(
                        "step 1": { echo "hello" },
                        "step 2": { echo "world" },
                        "step 3": { echo "world" }
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Blue Ocean Parallel Steps]

To Make your Stages Parallel use this, both solutions show up very similar in Blue Ocean :

```java
    pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Example Stage') {
            parallel {
                stage('Stage 1') {
                    steps { sh 'echo stage 1 passed' }
                }
                stage('Stage 2') {
                    steps { sh 'echo stage 2 passed' }
                }
                stage('Stage 3') {
                    steps { sh 'echo stage 3 passed' }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Blue Ocean Parallel Stages]

Comment: but this make steps parallel, not stages. Anyway, I haven't found better solution yet.

Answer (score 2):

You need to upgrade the Declarative Pipeline plugin on your Jenkins to [Version 1.2 (Sept 21, 2017)](https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/09/25/declarative-1/) or above

Answer (score 1):

In declarative pipeline, in case if you want to add stage, inside steps, this nesting is also possible.

If the steps are same in that case you can declare `step` as a `function`.

```
def steps  = ['first', 'second'] 
def generateSteps(stepLabel) {
    return {
        step("${stepLabel}") {
                echo "Running on ${stepLabel}"
        }
    }
}
def parallelStepMap = steps.collectEntries {
    ["${it}" : generateSteps(it)]
}
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('non-parallel stage') {
            steps {
                echo 'This stage will be executed first.'
            }
        }
 
        stage('parallel stage') {
            steps {
                script {
                    parallel parallelStepMap
                }
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

General need is to execute different stages into different nodes.
in such case above function can be modified to execute on different agent `nodes` as follows.

```
def agents  = ['master', 'agent1', 'agent2']
 
 
def generateStage(nodeLabel) {
    return {
        stage("Runs on ${nodeLabel}") {
            node(nodeLabel) {
                echo "Running on ${nodeLabel}"
            }
        }
    }
}
def parallelStagesMap = agents.collectEntries {
    ["${it}" : generateStage(it)]
}
pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage('non-parallel stage') {
            steps {
                echo 'This stage will be executed first.'
            }
        }
 
        stage('parallel stage') {
            steps {
                script {
                    parallel parallelStagesMap
                }
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

With `nodelabel` defined inside the function and agent `none` during start of pipeline, the stages will be executed into different nodes.