# Build 2 Jobs Concurrently With Default Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I would like to build two projects at the same time since one is 64 bit and the other is 32 bit. Currently I have my Jenkins setup to build both using its two executors. But when using the Jenkins Pipeline scripting language, it always builds them sequentially instead of concurrently.

Here is my script which builds the 32 bit project first and then 64 bit

```
node('master') {
    stage('Build')
    {
        stage('32')
        {
            build 'Short'
        }

        stage('64')
        {
            build 'Long'
        }
    }
}
```

NOTE - I don't want to use a plugin like [Workflow](https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/parallelism-and-distributed-builds-jenkins) if I don't have to

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Jenkins User Documentation, Advanced Scripted Pipeline, Parallel execution](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#parallel-execution):

```
stage('Build') {
    parallel 32: {
        ...
    },
    64: {
        ...
    }
}
```

and also [Jenkins pipeline with parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43212418/1744774).

Comment: awesome, it worked! i just had to increase the number of executors on my master node from 2 to 3 and it was able to run them in parallel with your example!